# Populating plotly graph with firebase database array

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, web, plotly

How can I populate the plotly Bar chart based on data from **Firebase back end**.  If I put the graph code and array variables **inside the for each** array **only one value is added** to the graph but if I place the plotly graph code and array variable array and array2 **outside the for each loop**, then the value of the **array is undefined** outside the for each loop.  How can I populate the x and y with values from the database
//example array[John, Kevin, Mel]
//example array2 [45,56,67]

```
var array= [];
var array2 = [];
firebase.database().ref("Scores").child('gameOneScores').on('value', function(snap){

   snap.forEach(function(childNodes){

    array.push(childNodes.val().finalScore);
    array2.push(childNodes.val().nameOfPlayer);

    var data = [{
    type: 'bar',
    x: [array],
    y: [array2],
    orientation: 'h'
  }];
  Plotly.newPlot('graphDiv', data);


      console.log(array);
      console.log(array2);

  });
  console.log("New array "+this.array);
```

The console log here is undefined as I can't access the array values inside the for each loop. I tried and tried but still no luck.  Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry solved it I was using *[array]* inside the bracket instead of just **array**.

```
 var data = [{
    type: 'bar',
    x: array,
    y: array2,
    orientation: 'h'
  }];
  Plotly.newPlot('graphDiv', data);
```